# Can I skip the complex(imaginary results) in a numpy array?

Tags: python, math, calculation

Suppose I have a function like `sqrt(x)` and I am passing a list of numbers through it `[-1,0,1]`.

This is going to give me an error saying that a negative argument is passed inside the square root function and the program is going to be halted after that without even checking for the 0 and 1 for which I would have gotten the real and "allowed" results in the first place.

Is there a way I can command python to ignore the values for which it would give errors and move on to the next part of the list?

Perhaps an algorithm like:

```
Start
x =  [-1,0,1]
Pass this list through the function sqrt(x)
Ignore the values for which the function is going to the complex regime
Give the results ([-,0,1])
End
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `-` supposed to mean in `([-,0,1])`?

Comment: Not if you use the csqrt function.  You'll get an array of complex numbers, with real and imaginary parts.  That might be useful if it's likely that you'll have negative inputs.

Comment: @matszwecja, The hyphen would denote that the results are complex and thus out of regime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@matszwecja's answer assumes you can tell a priori which arguments give complex-valued answers. This is true for your `sqrt` example, but not in the general case. To filter after execution, a slight remix would be:

```py
import numpy as np
arguments = [-1, 0, 1]
results = [x ** 0.5 for x in arguments]  # stand in for your more general function


# use numpy for the filtering, for convenience
real_valued_args = np.array(arguments)[~np.iscomplex(results)]
```

Comment: Is there a way that shall enable me to do so to a function that I have predefined as well? +1

Comment: Well, of course, the `results =...` line is a placeholder for any operation. The logic should work, still.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = [-1, 0, 1]
print(np.sqrt(x))
```

numpys sqrt function is not throwing an error and returning only valid results.

Comment: My function is not so straightforward, there are various root functions scattered throughout the expression and in that case I am receiving an error saying that negative values encountered in the sqrt function.

Answer (score 0):

Just do an explicit filter of your data:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([-1,0,1])

filtered_arr = arr[arr >= 0]

print(np.sqrt(filtered_arr))
```

Comment: As Dominick has suggested, you have assumed that I am working with easily identifiable values for which I am getting the error but that's quite not the case and hence this solution is not the right for me.